# Can we use the uniqueness theorem here?

Tags: complex-analysis

The function $sin(\frac{1}{z})$ is equal to 0 at the infinite sequence of points $\frac{1}{\pi}, \frac{1}{2\pi} . . . . .$ which converges to $0$. Can we use the Uniqueness Theorem of analytic functions to conclude that $sin(\frac{1}{z})$ is identically 0?

Comment: $sin(\frac{1}{z})$ is not analytic at zero (has an essential singularity) so obviously the uniqueness theorem doesn't apply

Comment: You need the function to be analytic at the limit point as well. This is not the case here.

Comment: In fact, applying uniqueness theorem and the fact that $\sin(1/z)$ is not identically zero gives you exactly the conclusion that $\sin(1/z)$ is not analytic at $z = 0$.